# Using supertest to test separate nodes run by naught

Tags: node.js, express, continuous-deployment, supertest, continuous-delivery

I'm using a naught (https://github.com/andrewrk/naught) to run my node.js app on multiple cores and also have naught giving me zero downtime deploys with only one machine.

I'd like to use supertest (https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) for testing each individual node before it's up - for some basic integration tests which will give that node the 'OK' for going into to the pool (before then node can process.send('online')).

If the supertest tests are a part of the individual node - will it close a request-response cycle with itself (good) or just send an http request to the entire pool (bad) ?

If not - is there any other way of doing this ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually figured this out, more or less...

I'll launch and test each node on a 'staging' port, and if it tests OK I'll add it to the pool.

example can be found here : https://gist.github.com/avnersorek/ae36e1de73bca2a8e188